# Preserve original colour when wrapping a transparent background PNG around a cylinder using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, png

Using the following code and three.js I am able to wrap a transparent background PNG around a cylinder..

```
actualCode(THREE);
function actualCode(THREE) {
    
    let texture;

    //Preload image, then trigger rendering
    const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    //Example with image hosted from Imgur:
    texture = loader.load("https://automation.stickermonkey.shop/codeplayground/glassetch/2-wrapdesign/images/defaultimage.png", function(_tex) {
        console.log("texture loaded");
        // /*Debugging:*/ setTimeout(() => document.body.appendChild(texture.image), 100);
        //views 17.5=front | 355=side | 139.6=back
        renderImageSolo(355);
    });

    function renderImageSolo(angle) {
        //Init just main renderer / scene
        const solo_renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            antialias: true,
            preserveDrawingBuffer: true, // <-- avoid plain black image
            alpha: true
        });
        solo_renderer.setSize(500, 500);
        document.body.appendChild(solo_renderer.domElement);
        const solo_scene = new THREE.Scene();
        //Init camera orig values =(30, 400.0 / 400, 1, 1000)
        
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(80, 500.0 / 500, 1, 100);
        camera.position.set(0, 1.3, 10);
        camera.lookAt(solo_scene.position);
        //Set an ambient light
        //const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xddd8d9); // soft white light
        //solo_scene.add(light);
        

        //Draw painting alone orig values -= (1.5, 1.5, 8.3, 240, 1, true)
        const paintgeom = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(3, 3, 8.3, 1000, 10, true);
        const paintmaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
            color: (0xddd8d9),
            map: texture,
        });
        
        const paint = new THREE.Mesh(paintgeom, paintmaterial);
        
        
        //Add paint to scene
        solo_scene.add(paint);
        //Rotate paint by angle
        paint.rotation.y = angle;
        //paint.color.set(0xddd8d9);
        //Draw result
        //solo_scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x000000, 0);
        solo_renderer.setClearColor( 0xddd8d9, 0 ); // the default
        solo_renderer.render(solo_scene, camera);
        //Save result
        saveImage(solo_renderer.domElement, "defaultimage.png")
    }

    //Save canvas as image by posting it to special url on server
    function saveImage(canvas, filename) {
        const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        const fileNameEnc = encodeURIComponent(filename);
        fetch('./photo_upload.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
            body: `data=${dataUrl}&filename=${fileNameEnc}`,
        })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            alert(data.message); //Show ajax result
        })
        .catch(err => { //Handle errors
            console.log(err);
            alert(err.message);
        });
    }
};
```

The original img in looks like this...

[image]

And the current output is this this..

[image]

The wrap side of it is working as I expected but the image is being turned into black when I wanted/expected it to preserve the original colour from the input image.

Can anyone tell me how to have it keep the original image colour or better still be able to change the colour to any I want?

Comment: `MeshStandardMaterial` needs lights to show their color. Without light, you'll get solid black on any part of the mesh that is visible. If you just want to show the exact color of your PNG image, I recommend you use `MeshBasicMaterial`, because it doesn't require illumination, which removes a layer of complexity in your color pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Marquizzo's comment for pointing me in the right direction.

Switching from `MeshStandardMaterial` to `MeshBasicMaterial` alone didn't solve the issue, but when used with...

`MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, transparent: true } );`

I got the exact desired results.